# How to change createstacknavigator route name

Tags: react-native

```
  root: createBottomTabNavigator(
    { 
   Main: createStackNavigator(
        {
          first: screen1,
          second: screen2,
          third: screen3,
        }
 }

createBottomTabNavigator button name is "Main" it is ok but. what i want is that,  i want to add language option to app so that "Main" text should be changed.
```

when i add like this:

```
 root: createBottomTabNavigator(
        { 
       i18.t('newName'): createStackNavigator(
            {
              first: screen1,
              second: screen2,
              third: screen3,
            }
     }
```

*it is not acceptable. how can i handle that ?*

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator/#title

```
Main: createStackNavigator(
        {
          first: screen1,
          second: screen2,
          third: screen3,
        },
        navigationOptions: { title: i18.t('newName') },
```